# Implementing google API autocomplete without creating an actual map

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, autocomplete

As the title says, I am trying to use a location suggestion by using google API autocomplete without creating a google map. I've found some code on multiple sites and tried to put it together, filling in the missing parts, but so far it hasn't work. I was wondering if anyone knows how google API works and could help me out, thanks!

HTML:

```
<head>
    ....
    <script src="file.js"></script>
    ....
</head>
<body>
    ....
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="university" onfocus="geolocate()" placeholder="Name of University" required>
    ....
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initialize" async defer></script>
</body>
```

JS:

```
/*global google */
var autocomplete;

function initialize() {
  "use strict";

  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById("university"), {types: ["geocode"]});
}

function geolocate() {
  "use strict";

  var geolocation, circle;

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
      geolocation = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an API key?

Comment: Yes. I just didn't want to include it in on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is provided a [Place Autocomplete example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) without any dependency to `google.maps.Map` class:

```js
function initMap() {
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  

  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
 
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
      return;
    }

    var address = '';
    if (place.address_components) {
      address = [
        (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
      ].join(' ');
    }

    document.getElementById('placeInfo').innerHTML = '<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address;    
  });
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
        height: 100%;
}
.controls {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 32px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#pac-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 300px;
}

#pac-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}

.pac-container {
  font-family: Roboto;
}
```

```html
 <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text"
        placeholder="Enter a location"/>
 <pre id="placeInfo"></pre>
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
```

[image]